# Selecting records from subquery on multiple columns

Tags: sqlite

I'd like to do something like this:

Suppose I have two tables, myTable1 and myTable2.  Suppose both of these tables have columns myColumn1 and myColumn2.

```
update
   myTable1
set
   myTable1.myFlagColumn = 1
where
    myTable1.myColumn1, myTable1.myColumn2
       in
          (select myTable2.myColumn1, myTable2.myColumn2 from myTable2)
```

Essentially, I want to change a value in myTable1 if there are any rows where the two columns in myTable1 and myTable2 match.

Is this possible?

Comment: my suggestion is use separate select query for each column

Comment: Using a separate select query for each column isn't the same.  If myTable2 has rows ((1, 2), (3, 4)) and myTable1 has (1, 4), separate selects per column will be positive, when he wants a negative result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but you will use an EXISTS clause:

```
 update
    myTable1
 set
    myTable1.myFlagColumn = 1
 where
     EXISTS
     (select * FROM myTable2 WHERE myTable2.myColumn1 = myTable1.myColumn1 
     AND myTable2.myColumn2 = myTable1.myColumn2)
```